# "invalid operands to binary expression" when using custom struct as index of map in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

The code:

```
struct Tag {
    std::string left_tag, right_tag;
};
```

When I try to use `this->_tags[__tag] = true;`, I got the error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__functional_base:63:21: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const Tag' and 'const Tag')
        {return __x < __y;}
                ~~~ ^ ~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/map:1207:17: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::less<Tag>::operator()' requested here
            if (__tree_.value_comp().key_comp()(__k, __nd->__value_.__cc.first))
                ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/map:1376:36: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::map<Tag, bool, std::__1::less<Tag>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const Tag, bool> > >::__find_equal_key' requested here
    __node_base_pointer& __child = __find_equal_key(__parent, __k);
                                   ^
/Users/xxx/GitHubWorking/MarkupUtils/Syntax.h:69:20: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::map<Tag, bool, std::__1::less<Tag>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const Tag, bool> > >::operator[]' requested here
        this->_tags[__tag] = true;
                   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/utility:419:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'pair<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'const Tag'
operator< (const pair<_T1,_T2>& __x, const pair<_T1,_T2>& __y)
^
1 error generated.
```

I am stunned by the series of long stl errors.

According to the most deep error, it is caused by use of `const Tag`, but there does not seem to be any in my code.

Comment: Do you think everyone can see your code?

Comment: You're using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: @chris How do you figure? I don't see any issue with anything in their `Tag` struct. The `{return __x < __y;}` is from the internals of `Xcode`s implementation.

Comment: @Cyber, The index to their map is `__tag`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define an `operator<` for example

```
struct Tag
{
    std::string left_tag, right_tag;

    bool operator< (const Tag& rhs) const
    {
        return this->left_tag < rhs.left_tag ||
               (this->left_tag == rhs.left_tag && this->right_tag < rhs.right_tag);
    }
};
```

This will define the less-than operator to sort two `Tag` instances. As written in the above example, this will sort by preferring `left_tag`, then `right_tag`.

Comment: or use a functor that does the comparison, and use it in the map constructor.

Comment: @sam that is also an option, but if you're going to use this class as the key in a map, you might as well define the operator within the `struct`.

Comment: And what if you can't modify your struct to add the operator overload? (e.g. a struct defined in a private library). In this case you can't use the const qualifier and the error will be still here.

Comment: @JoeAspara If the members of the `struct` are `public`, then you can define a free function that takes two objects and compares them. For the OP's example that would look [like this](http://cpp.sh/82xwr).